# SyntaxError: invalid syntax I have checked for mix of Tabs & Spaces

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
        for urls in new_keywords
            if urls not in old_keywords
                upload_keywords.append(urls)
```

And my error:

```
  File "controller.py", line 56
    for urls in new_keywords
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I had this error before and the issue was a mix of spaces and tabs as indent. I have checked this and with my editor I can see only dots (spaces) but it doesn't seem to work? any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the colons `:` at the end of the `if` and `for` flow control statements.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski oh such a silly mistake lol! Thanks all I seriously tried to fix this with indent for like 10minutes and missed what is in front of me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a colon, it should be like:

```
for urls in new_keywords:
    if urls not in old_keywords:
        upload_keywords.append(urls)
```

That's why you get the invalid syntax error

Answer (score 3):

You missed a colon on each of the first 2 lines of your snippet.

Change

```
for urls in new_keywords
    if urls not in old_keywords
```

To

```
for urls in new_keywords:
    if urls not in old_keywords:
```

You should always put colons after `for` statements (as well as `while`, `if` and some other)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some colons

```
for urls in new_keywords: # <======== here
    if urls not in old_keywords: # <= and here
        upload_keywords.append(urls)
```